# ¿Como pasar parametros en las cabeceras - Headers Angular 4?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, post

### Angular 4

Saludos comunidad, estoy intentando pasar unos parametros por las cabeceras en una petición post pero me genera error, me dice que no se esta enviando los parametros en le headers, alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

```
registerHome(user_to_registerHome){
    let params = JSON.stringify(user_to_registerHome);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'},{'token':this.getToken});

    return this._http.post(this.url+'consolaseguridad-service/createUser', params, {headers: headers})
                      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: vale, gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampliando la respuesta de @Findelias, la cabecera `token` no existe, la cosa debería ser así:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json', 'charset=utf-8;')
headers.append('Authorization', this.getToken);

return this._http.post(this.url+'consolaseguridad-service/createUser', params,)
                      .map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: Gracias funciono correctamente

Comment: Buena observación

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto.

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json', 'charset=utf-8;')

return this._http.post(this.url+'consolaseguridad-service/createUser', params,)
                      .map(res => res.json());
```

Si te da algún otro error coméntalo y lo vemos.

Comment: Gracias funciono correctamente

Comment: Si puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta, harás un favor al resto de la comunidad que podrá encontrar las soluciones más fácilmente en el futuro.